# How to select data based on search result clicked mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Title was a little hard to write clearly so let me explain.
I am using PHP and have made the scripts to search a database and output that data in a html table using a loop. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ek3k.jpg example there.

All is good here but I am not to sure how to go about the following.

I want to set some global variables such as searchfname based on the link you click on the table.

I will add a hyperlink tag to the id section but how do I upon clicking that link set the global variables to the value of the other columns such as First Name and Surname.

Can I somehow grab the value of the link and use that in a query to find the details?

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Luke.

Comment: what part of your table would be a link?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please add your code to the question and try to be more precise. Keep in mind that we do not know your situation.

Comment: So the link is going to be the ID column as seen in the picture. I want them to click this and have the program set some global variables for the rest of the details i.e. First Name, Surname.

Comment: since you know already during creation of the table which element your handling in terms of row/column you can prepare a link accordingly beforehand and put all information in there

Comment: But the info would be different for each user?